# How to create a process which can execute concurrently with respect to java process

Tags: java

I want to create a runtime process from java application.
The java application should return immediately once it starts that runtime process. And java process can even exit before the completion of runtime process.

Can i achieve this ???

But as per java docs says :
There is no requirement that a process represented by a Process object execute asynchronously or concurrently with respect to the Java process that owns the Process object.

I created a runtime process which will call cmd.exe and perform unzip. And this unzip is taking very long time for huge files. So, what i thought is, is there any possibily  from java to just start the runtime process(i.e unzip) and don't wait till it completes, and proceed further. Even it can exit also, but runtime process should complete its work.

Comment: The Javadoc may say that, but nevertheless it does work that way on Windows and Unix-like systems.

Comment: oh.. there is no way to do this in windows using java